# Is there a simpler way to call Contains() on a string that is potentially null?

Tags: c#

Is there a simpler or less ugly way to call .Contains() on a string that is potentially null then by doing:

```
Assert.IsTrue((firstRow.Text ?? "").Contains("SomeText"));
```

Comment: This is already < 10 chars. How much simpler?

Comment: When I read this line of code, I have to mentally compile and execute it to make sure that it behaves the way I think it does. Granted, this example is pretty trivial, but going down this path lends itself to more complicated lines of code. Also note, an Assert class will usually also have an [IsNotNull method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.isnotnull(v=VS.80).aspx), which could be used here as a previous statement. By lumping these two conditions together your unit test is less effective at identifying the cause of a bug.

Answer (score 20):

I'd suggest using `Assert.That` syntax:

```
Assert.That(firstRow.Text, Does.Contain("SomeText"));
```

If you need to check that text is not containing a certain string:

```
Assert.That(firstRow.Text, Does.Not.Contain("SomeText"));
```

Comment: "That" doesn't come as standard in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting. Where does it come from?

Comment: It is from NUnit.Framework namespace of NUnit library

Answer (score 6):

I think any of these alternatives are better, even though they are not quite as short:

```
// 1
Assert.IsTrue(firstRow.Text != null && firstRow.Text.Contains("SomeText"));

// 2
Assert.IsNotNull(firstRow.Text);
Assert.IsTrue(firstRow.Text.Contains("SomeText"));

// 3
var text = firstRow.Text;
Assert.IsTrue(text != null && text.Contains("SomeText"));
```

I think "simple" is a subjective term.  Simple, to me, means "clear and easy to read", not "fewest number of characters".

Considering that this code appears to be part of a unit test, Option #2 would be best, because then you can tell from reading the test results whether the test failed due to a null value or failed because the value did not contain the expected text.  Otherwise, you would have to re-execute this test with a debugger and look at the value at runtime  in order to distinguish between these two cases.

"Make things as simple as possible, but not simpler." - Albert Einstein

Comment: Shouldn't those be && operators, not || ?

Comment: @KingNestor - Yep! I had to think about the original code for a minute and work that out.  I think that illustrates why the original code is not clear.

Comment: Options 1 & 2 are better. Option 3 is not an alternative I would use. The purpose of an _Assert_ is to throw an error when debugging and the compiler will convert it to the C# equivalent of a NOP when compiling with the DEBUG flag turned off. But _var text_ declares a variable that is added to the stack regardless (although the compiler may be clever enough to optimism it away).

Comment: @David Clarke - I see your point, and it does make sense. Option 3 is not really different from Option 1, but I included it because the OP was asking for "simpler". Option 3 removes the duplicate code referncing the `firstRow.Text` property; a trivial "simpliciation".  Also note, your point would be spot on if these were calls to Debug.Assert, which is conditionally excluded by the compiler for non-debug builds as you mention. However, this code appears to be using an [Assert class from a unit testing framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245302(v=VS.80).aspx).

Comment: Yeah, it's not obvious in the question whether the _Assert_ is part of a test or just used to demonstrate the conditional. I think your option 2 is the most explicit and will give better feedback on failure, i.e. was it null or did the match fail.

Answer (score 3):

This is one character shorter, but frankly I like your original code better.

```
Assert.IsTrue((firstRow.Text + "").Contains("SomeText"));
```

Comment: @nawfal - now I have to upvote all the non-trivial answers out of guilt :)

Comment: Haha, come on it doesn't matter. I'm not liking the simple if text != null && kind of cleaner syntaxes these days, I liked your different thinking :)

Comment: @nawfal - god - I *hate* syntax like that - so chatty.  Honestly I think OPs original syntax is the best of anything else on this page.  I just wanted to be cute here :)

Answer (score 2):

No, there aren't any. But you could write an extension method for that:

```
public static bool SContains(this string source, string query)
{
    return source != null && source.Contains(query);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would expect the string being null exposes a different error to the string not being "SomeText", in which case it would be better to have two unit tests to test the different outcomes.

In terms of methods how about using StringAssert and IsNotNull?

```
Assert.IsNotNull(firstRow.Text);

StringAssert.Contains(firstRow.Text, "SomeText");
```

(I am assuming this relates to a unit test)

Answer (score 1):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.stringassert(v=vs.100).aspx

StringAssert class can be used to easily assert whether or not the stringUnderTest contains the specefied string

Answer (score 0):

I think a plain No,

This would be a little less ugly and gets the implied readability

```
If(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstRow.Text))
    Assert.IsTrue(firstRow.Text.Contains("SomeText"));
```

Comment: looks like you're missing an ! in the if condition.

Comment: @Dr.Wily'sApprentice Sorry, thanks for spotting it, terrible mistake

Comment: "terrible" is not how I would describe it. :) I had a few mistakes in my own answer.

Comment: @nawfal Do you think so ? actually everystring (not null) would return true for "", try it out

Comment: Oops, i meant this wouldnt work when firstRow.Text = "" and "SomeText" = "". Hope you got me :D

Comment: @V4Vendetta lets assume `IsTrue` is a static function defined on `Assert` class. Now how is that function hit if firstRow.Text becomes ""?? You never know what the dynamic values of a string variable can be, so assuming that the code fails when the variable substituting for "SomeText" is also "". If it still works for you, please let me know how..

Answer (score 0):

I would generally use something more like the following which is longer and less clever but idiomatic c# and the intent is obvious.

```
Assert.IsTrue( !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(firstRow.Text))
Assert.IsTrue( firstRow.Text.Contains("SomeText"));
```

In my interpretation of the question, the empty string is an error condition. That's one reason I prefer my version - the context for the test is explicit. If I wanted to include the empty string as a valid result I would use the following as the first condition, again making the test explicit:

```
Assert.IsNotNull(firstRow.Text)
```

To me this is far more important than shortening the code. In a month when I (or someone else) come back to make changes to the code it is obvious what the intent of the test is. In the original question, not so much.

Comment: this wouldnt work when firstRow.Text = "" and "SomeText" = "".

Comment: @nawfal - Is "" even a valid value for "SomeText"? Assuming that it is not a valid value, I think that's a great reason for not doing what the original code is doing; edge cases could cause unexpected behavior.

Comment: @myself - eh...let me think about what I said for a minute. I'm not sure I agree with my own point...

Comment: I think the point is that it's not obvious from the code what the author intended. Is null a valid value for `firstRow.Text`? Or is null not a valid value for `firstRow.Text` and was the author thinking "well, I know that "SomeText" will never be "", so this condition will just always work out to what I want it to be."?

Comment: +1 for your above rather funny comment :). @Dr.Wily'sApprentice Yes its a valid value. We do not know what kinda string "SomeText" can be. The OP knows his requirement better. But what if his code is all about checking if a dynamic string generated within the code contains another not hardcoded string? In such cases he doesnt know what value those strings can have. The code should never fail anyways. We cant assume from here what OP's requirement is, all we can do is provide an idiot proof solution

Comment: firstRow.text can not be null, the code he posted in question itself helps us with that. It can be any valid string that checks with any other valid string, which is all what we can assume..

Comment: @nawful - hehe, thanks! :) I agree with much of what you're saying. Granted, we don't know the actual requirements, but the code does not give me a high degree of confidence that the edge cases involving "" were considered when it was written. It seems to me that whether or not this code has a bug is fairly uncertain.  It's kind of like science; we can never be 100% sure that any theory is actually true, but we do have varying degrees of confidence in them based on the evidence that we observe.

Comment: @Dr.Wily'sApprentice you cant still assume. We ought to give a perfect solution. Lets say the OP is trying to compare two notepads. The correct file has a piece of string "xyz". Now the user/candidate needs to enter in a blank notepad exactly what is present in correct notepad file. So the internal logic is to compare the two notepad strings. And the code should give if any text was inserted, deleted or replaced. `Consists` will be a frequently used method in such operations. Now what if the correct file itself is blank notepad?

Comment: In that case the candidate might leave a blank answer file checking which the tool wil decide as the output is wrong.

Comment: //If I wanted to include the empty string as a valid result I would use firstRow.Text != null as the first condition//

But you didn't. There is no reason to assume empty string is invalid condition from OP's question..

Comment: That is the point. The OP is simply avoiding throwing an exception by coalescing firstRow.Text to the empty string. This smells of clever coding and if as you have suggested previously, the test is _Contains("")_, then a null value will pass the test. This might actually be the desired behavior but it seems unlikely. It is more likely null is an invalid value but by not testing explicitly for null the intent is opaque.

Comment: @DavidClarke I get your point completely, you have a point. But my point is, you are still assuming what he wants. May be he is thinking like you, may be he is not. To give the benefit of doubt, its better not to assume. Given then nature of his requirement from his one line code, all we can say is he doesn't exactly try to avoid an exception, rather, when null is passed he needs an empty string to be compared. There are several cases of needing to interpret null as "" and not an error condition.

Comment: Eg, 1)if you are reading empty string values from database (in such cases DBNull), 2) getting datagridviewcell string value if its uninitialized with any valid value previously etc.



Now forget all that about null. What if firstRow.Text is "" and not null? On what basis is that an invalid condition for you? How can a string not dynamically have a value of ""??If the OP needs to translate null to "", does that mean all "" are invalid condition? From his code he is only checking for null, not "". Please include my name when you reply, I dont see the notification otherwise :)

Comment: @nawfal, the OP used an _Assert_ in his question. Can we agree that implies either unit testing or debugging? And the OP is explicitly testing if the string contains "SomeText". So the failure conditions are that the string is null, empty, or doesn't contain "SomeText". Option 2 in Dr. Wily's Apprentice answer is clearly the best way to represent this. Rather than continue to discuss semantics based on our interpretation of the OP's intent, perhaps it would be better to ask the question of the OP.

Comment: @DavidClarke OP is testing explicitly with "SomeText" ?? I would only conclude thats a dynamic value. No string being empty is not a failure condition. I again ask how is that you are reaching to that conclusion?? Can't the OP use a string variable there of whose value he has no clue of? The failure condition is just 'doesnt contain". null condition may be or may not be failure for him, but he cast's it to a valid string which is "". Now Assert can be true when "SomeText" becomes "". So OP wouldnt've considered null as failure condition, rather he is just translatin it to a meaningful value

Comment: To make things explicitly and lucidly. From the OP's code `Assert.IsTrue((firstRow.Text ?? "").Contains("SomeText"));` only AND ONLY means (without assuming) null value is valid here which should be treated as fair to compare it against "SomeText". And I believe "SomeText" can be any value (again by not assuming). From the given code, null is invalid only if "SomeText" can not be "". Which I do not believe. `The difference between us boils down to this`. I got no idea why is "SomeText" merely s o m e t e x t for you. And I'm not even talking of whitespaces here which is another assumption!!

Comment: @DavidClarke my point is I based my interpretation on some basis while I find your basis a bit far-fetched. Hence I posted all this. I do quit..